# [20.4.3 LTS][EHL] Boot up slowly issue

Tags: boot, drivers, 20.04, kernel

I'm trying to install Ubuntu Desktop 20.04 on Elkhart Lake platform.

I've downloaded and installed Ubuntu Desktop 20.04 from [Intel IoT](https://ubuntu.com/download/iot/intel-iotg), then I realize that it takes a long time when system boot up, it may take over 120 seconds from boot up logo until enter desktop.

Will this issue comes from drivers, Kernel of something else?

Here is my Kernel version: `Linux nvis1482-NViS-1482-Series 5.13.0-1008-intel #8-Ubuntu SMP Thu Nov 18 14:10:58 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

How can I check the possible root cause of this issue?

By the way, how can I check current driver version of Intel chipset, PCH driver, CSE version, display driver, network driver and audio driver version like Windows?

Answer (score 0):

Finally found how to resolve this issue

1. enter command "sudo vi /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf" in terminal
2. add a new line "blacklist pinctrl_elkhartlake" , save and exit editor mode
3. enter command "update-initramfs –u" in terminal
4. reboot system to apply change

Comment: Be a little wary of creating questions and then answering with a 'boiler-plate' answer: https://askubuntu.com/a/1411665/57576

Comment: ok, just because this solution fix both questions, so I copy/paste the answer.