# [22.04][EHL] can not shutdown and reboot

Tags: 22.04

I've installed Ubuntu 22.04 on EHL platform, when I trying to reboot or shutdown, system will hang up and could not shutdown or reboot.
This issue also existed on 20.04 and 21.10. Is there anyone can help to resolve this issue?

Comment: I expirienced the same issue and opened a bug : https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1970065

Comment: Currently I found a non-official kernel from internet which resolve the boot time over 2 mins and could not shutdown/reboot properly issue. Which version is 5.15.9-xenomai-3.2.1 #113 SMP IRQPIPE Fri Apr 15 16:36:32 CST 2022 x86_64 GNU/Linux. However, is there anyone know when will official kernel version be released?

Answer (score 0):

Finally found how to resolve this issue

1. enter command "sudo vi /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf" in terminal
2. add a new line "blacklist pinctrl_elkhartlake" , save and exit editor mode
3. enter command "update-initramfs –u" in terminal
4. reboot system to apply change